# jQuery iframe modal close on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a jQuery Modal dialog with an iframe in it, the iframe includes a form. When a user submits the form, I would like to close down the modal dialog.

How can I do that?

jquery modal script on index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showRegDialog(url) {
    $(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var horizontalPadding = 30;
            var verticalPadding = 30;
            $('<iframe id="externalSite" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" class="externalSite" src="' + url + '" />').dialog({
                title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : 'Choose your location',
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 700,
                height: 700,
                modal: true,
                resizable: true,
                autoResize: true,
                overlay: {
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    background: "black"
                }

            }).width(700 - horizontalPadding).height(700 - verticalPadding);            

    });
}
</script>
```

link on index.php to call showRegDialog modal:

```
<a href="javascript:showRegDialog('/register.php');">Register now</a>
```

This is the content of the register.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call javascript function in parent window like this:

```
parent.yourJsFunction();
```

put it in "onsubmit" in your form.

Comment: Just noticed something, if I try to open the dialog a second time and submit the form, it doesn't close it. Only works for the first time for some reason...

Comment: can you please assist with my question?

Comment: Can you post a link to your webpage?

Comment: It can be that you need to call the destroy function for the dialog after you close it, because if you open it the second time, it may happen that you have 2 elements with the same ID. Just a guess

Comment: I get a Uncaught TypeError: parent.closeModal is not a function, both functions are in the right spots on the iframe and in the main window

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [**`close`**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#method-close)

Give your form an id.

```
$("#formID").submit(function(){
    parent.closeModal();
});

// function for closing modal window (in parent page)
function closeModal() {
    $("#externalSite").dialog("close");
}
```

Comment: But I need to launch that command only after the form submits, and the form is inside the iframe, so how do I implement your solution? thanks

Comment: Doesn't work for some reason.. See this: http://pastebin.com/npaBAt6a when I submit the form it doesn't close down the dialog. just submits the form..